# Adding GeometryModel3D to Model3DGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am trying to create a wpf app that shows an animated 3D model. I have working code to create the model in BuildWave (I know this works as I have used it before). However, when I moved the code to a background worker in the class of the wpf window, I get the error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

```
    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = BuildWave();
    }

    private void worker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeometryModel3D model = (GeometryModel3D)e.Result;
        mGeometry = model.Clone();    //mGeometry is a private member of the window
        if (group.Children.Contains(mGeometry))   //error is on this line
        {
            group.Children.Remove(mGeometry);    //group is a Model3DGroup added in xaml
        }
        group.Children.Add(mGeometry);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Added geometry to group");
    }
```

I have searched for solutions to this and found a post that covers a problem with the same error ([The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it?rq=1)), which suggests using Dispatcher.Invoke(). However, when I try that:

```
    private void worker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeometryModel3D model = (GeometryModel3D)e.Result;
        mGeometry = model.Clone();

        group.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (group.Children.Contains(mGeometry))
            {
                group.Children.Remove(mGeometry);
            }
            group.Children.Add(mGeometry);    //error is now thrown on this line
        });

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Added geometry to group");
    }
```

This throws the error "Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.", and again there is a post covering a similar problem ([Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383174/cannot-use-a-dependencyobject-that-belongs-to-a-different-thread-than-its-parent)) which suggests freezing the model which I have done in BuildWave:

```
        GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(WaveMesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.YellowGreen));
        model.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();

        model.Freeze();
        return model;
```

What should I do to fix this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call in UI thread something like this:

```
public static Model3DCollection GetModel3DCollectionByTemplates(List<GeometryTemplate> geometryTemplates) {
        var modelCollection = new Model3DCollection();
        foreach (var geometryTemplate in geometryTemplates) {
            var positions = geometryTemplate.Positions;
            var indicies = geometryTemplate.Indicies;
            var normals = geometryTemplate.Normals;
            var meshGeometry3D = new MeshGeometry3D {
                Positions = new Point3DCollection(positions),
                TriangleIndices = new Int32Collection(indicies),
                Normals = new Vector3DCollection(normals)
            };
            var geometry = new GeometryModel3D(meshGeometry3D,
                new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine)));
            modelCollection.Add(geometry);
        }
        // =======================
        return modelCollection;
    }
```

But within Task (TPL) returns List of GeometryTemplate.
And simple Data wrapper class:

```
public class GeometryTemplate {
    public List<Point3D> Positions { get; private set; }
    public List<Int32> Indicies { get; private set; }
    public List<Vector3D> Normals { get; private set; }

    public GeometryTemplate(MeshGeometry3D meshGeometry3D) {
        SetPositions(meshGeometry3D.Positions);
        SetIndicies(meshGeometry3D.TriangleIndices);
        SetNormals(meshGeometry3D.Normals);
    }

    private void SetNormals(Vector3DCollection normals) {
        Normals = new List<Vector3D>(normals);
    }

    private void SetIndicies(Int32Collection triangleIndices) {
        Indicies = new List<Int32>(triangleIndices);
    }

    private void SetPositions(Point3DCollection positions) {
        Positions = new List<Point3D>(positions);
    }
}
```

And final point:

```
_model3DGroupContainer.Children = model3DCollection;
```

where _model3DGroupContainer is Model3DGroup

Answer (score 1):

For it works with no problem, prepare in your bgworker  all the data(lists of points, lists of a triangle vertices) for your geometry model and do not use the gui objects such as `Point3DCollection` or `Int32Collection` or geometries. Then, when you ready with it, create all your geometries etc. in your lambda method(you can gladly extract this creation to a method for more readability and call it in lambda), which you call on a dispatcher. This should work.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about the order of the code, and what operations could be done in which threads.. sorted now!